# How To Group 2 Arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, image, variables

I Wish To Echo Random Image With Name using php
This Is what I am Using To Echo Random Image

```
<?php
$cars=scandir('./cars');

unset($cars[0]);
unset($cars[1]);
$dream=array_rand($cars);
$dreamCar=$cars[$dream];
echo $dreamCar;
?>
```

Now I Wish To Group The image with Name
So I Did this

```
<?php
$title=Array("Ferrari","BMW");
echo $title[array_rand($title)];
?>
```

But I wish To set it in a Way that when BMW's Pic Is shown the name BMW itself should Echo & Not ferrari
Is It Possible??

Comment: You should use a data structure that has the image path and the name grouped together in the first place already (like an array of arrays, for example.)

Comment: The other option is of course that you store the random value in a variable, so that you can use the same value a second time.

Comment: As far as I can see you don't have any relationship between the image and the car's name. You could use the car's name as filename (with an counter as pre- or suffix) or you use some kind of data structure as suggested by CBroe . This could be an array in code or a database or whatever.